# Clicking the Apply button on QtQuick Dialog closes dialog

Tags: qt, dialog, qml

I have defined a QtQuick dialog with 3 buttons: **Apply**, **OK** and **Cancel**:

```
Dialog {
    id: myDialog
    standardButtons: StandardButton.Apply | StandardButton.Ok | StandardButton.Cancel

    onApply: console.log("Applying data")
    onAccepted: console.log("Saving data")
    onRejected: console.log("Cancel changes to data")

    Item { ... }
}
```

When I click OK and Cancel, the dialog closes as expected. When I click the Apply button, I would expect the dialog to remain open, but it closes as well.

Is there a way to hook it so the dialog remains open for that button while closing for the other two?

Comment: Try `onApply: visible = true` or call `open()`

Comment: This could be a temporary work-around until the bug @OlegShparber submitted is fixed. It hides the window temporarily and then re-displays it, so a bit of a visual annoyance, but doable.

Comment: I know about that so I suggest you try to show dialog again. See time of posting comment and answer. I just didn't post this as answer.

Answer (score 5):

It's a bug in Qt Quick Dialogs. As you can see [here](https://github.com/qtproject/qtquickcontrols/blob/dev/src/dialogs/qquickdialog.cpp#L338), dialog is closed regardless of what button was clicked. I've just submitted a [patch](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/97372/) to fix the problem.